# Hibernate with H2 database not working in netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

I can't get Hibernate to work with H2 database on netbeans with a really simple code. Please help! I get this error:

```
Testcase: initializationError(Teste):   Caused an ERROR
org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Here is the content of the files:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:./testeDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="HibernateAgoraVaiPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Pessoa</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:./testeDB"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Pessoa.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length=50, nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date aniversario;

    public Pessoa(){
    }

    public Date getAniversario() {
        return this.aniversario;
    }

    public void setAniversario(Date aniversario) {
        this.aniversario = aniversario;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

**Teste.java**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.junit.Test;


public class Teste {
    private EntityManager em;

    public Teste(){
        this.em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TesteHibernatePU").createEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void inserir(){
        // Instanciamos um objeto Pessoa, setando nome e data de nascimento
        Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa();
        p1.setNome("Jonnas Fonini");
        p1.setAniversario(new Date());

        Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa();
        p2.setNome("Luana Fonini");
        p2.setAniversario(new Date());

        Pessoa p3 = new Pessoa();
        p3.setNome("Fulano de Tal");
        p3.setAniversario(new Date());

        // Iniciamos a transação
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        // Aqui persistimos os objetos recém criados
        em.persist(p1);
        em.persist(p2);
        em.persist(p3);
        // E aqui efetuamos definitivamente a transação
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Test
    public void listar(){
        Collection <Pessoa> lista = em.createQuery("from Pessoa").getResultList();

        for (Pessoa p : lista){
            System.out.println(p.getId() + " – " + p.getNome() + " – " + p.getAniversario());
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the steps I made:

1) Created a new project in NetBeans (version 8.1)

2) Added the Hibernate Library to the project: right click over libraries > Add Library ... > Import > Hibernate 4.3.x

3) Downloaded the latest stable version of H2 from this link
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.3.176/h2-1.3.176.jar and added the jar as a library: right click over libraries > Add JAR/Folder > Selected the downloaded JAR file

4) Created a new Database connection in the Services tab: right click on databases > New connection ... > Selected new driver option > Picked the JAR file downloaded on step (3) > OK and Next > Left Username and password blank, just informed "jdbc:h2:./testeDB" (with no quotes) as the JDBC URL, and tested connection sucessfully > Select PUBLIC SCHEMA and Finished

5) Created a new Hibernate Configuration using the assistant: right click over "source-code packages" > New > Other > Hibernate > Assitant > Next, Next, selected the connection created on step (4)

6) Created a new Persistence Unit: right click over "source-code packages" > New > Other > Persistence > Persistence Unit > Next > Changed persistance library to Hibernate JPA 2.1, Database connection to the connection created on step (4), and table Strategy to Create

After that I edited both persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml to use org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

And finally I created a simple Person class and some test code. Also granted full permission on the project folder with

```
sudo chmod 777 -R HibernateAgoraVai
```

as I though might be a permission issue for creating the database file..

Comment: At first sign it looks like conflict on class path with hamcrest libraries. Please   verify if You have no more than one hamcrest library on classpath.

Comment: Can you please point me on how to do that? Under Libraries I do found several libraries pointing to "Hibernate 4.3.x" and "Hibernate 4.3.x(JPA2.1)", but after removing the ones with "Hibernate 4.3.x" and trying to run the tests again, the same error continued to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following problems with my code. Though might help anybody:

1) As pointed out by gauee, I should download and add hamcrest-core-1.3.jar to the tests library.

2) In the createEntityManagerFactory call I was passing "TesteHibernatePU". That must be the same name used in persistence.xml, which in this case is "HibernateAgoraVaiPU"

3) Another library was missing. Seems to be a dependency for JUnit 4.11 and later. Had to download jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar and add it to test libraries.

4) And finally I had to change Hibernate table strategy creation from "Create" to "Drop and create". Still quite don't understand about why I had to make this change.